# MSConfig what does it edit specifically in Windows 7, 8, 10?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, powershell

It used to be that the msconfig.exe used to edit the boot.ini from what I understand. Now in Windows 7, 8, and 10 I can't find out what it edits. Which part of the operating system does it change without using msconfig?

Comment: info from boot.ini now resides in the BCD store. See here for details: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721886%28v=ws.10%29.aspx The rest is in the registery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are asking about boot.ini I assume you are referring to just the boot tab? Prior to Windows Vista, msconfig changed boot.ini. As of Vista and later it changes the BCD, Boot Configuration Database. This is a registry hive that is not normally displayed by regedit. It lives in the file `\bcd.` in your "system" partition.